# Tikz: how to draw a fat arrow with arched lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

What type of parameters do I need to change in the draw function if I want to get an arrow-like below (see Picture) between my nodes?

[image]

Comment: pgf-manual, arrow shapes, arrow tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, minimum size=2em},
       alr/.style = {{Implies[]}-{Implies[]}}
                            ]
\node                   (A) {$S$};
\node   [right=of A]    (B) {$A$};
    %
\draw[double, alr] (A) -- (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For explanation see Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, *Arrow Tip Kind Implies*, on page 216.